# basename command confusion

Tags: linux, shell

Given the following command:

```
      $(basename "/this-directory-does-not-exist/*.txt" ".txt")
```

it outputs not only txt files but other files as well. On the other hand if I change ".txt" to something like "gobble de gook" it returns:

```
     *.txt
```

I'm confused with regard to why it returns the other extension types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem doesn't stem from `basename`, but from **inadvertent use of the shell's pathname expansion (globbing) feature due to lack of quoting**:

If you use the result of your command substitution (`$(...)`) *unquoted*:

```
$ echo $(basename "/this-directory-does-not-exist/*.txt" ".txt")
```

you effectively execute the following:

```
$ echo *   # unquoted '*' expands to all files and folders in the current dir
```

because `basename "/this-directory-does-not-exist/*.txt" ".txt"` returns literal `*` (it strips the extension from filename `*.txt`;
the reason that the filename *pattern* `*.txt` didn't expand to an actual filename is that the shell leaves globbing patterns that don't match anything unmodified (by default).)

If you *double-quote* the command substitution, the problem goes away:

```
$ echo "$(basename "/this-directory-does-not-exist/*.txt" ".txt")" # -> *
```

However, even with this problem resolved, **your `basename` command will only work correctly if the glob expands to *one* matching file**, because the syntax form you're using only supports *one* filename argument.

GNU `basename` and BSD `basename` support the non-POSIX `-s` option, which allows for multiple file operands from which to strip the extension:

```
basename -s .txt "/some-dir/*.txt"
```

---

Assuming you use `bash`, you can put it all together robustly as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

names=()        # initialize result array

files=( *.txt ) # perform globbing and capture matching paths in an array

# Since the shell by default returns a pattern as-is if there are no matches,
# we test the first array item for existence; if it refers to an existing
# file or dir., we know that at least 1 match was found.
if [[ -e ${files[0]} ]]; then
  # Apply the `basename` command with suffix-stripping to all matches
  # and read the results robustly into an array.
  # Note that just `names=( $(basename ...) )` would NOT work robustly.
  readarray -t names < <(basename -s '.txt' "${files[@]}")
  # Note: `readarray` requires Bash 4; in Bash 3.x, use the following:
  #    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a names < <(basename -s '.txt' "${files[@]}")
fi

# "${names[@]}" now contains an array of suffix-stripped basenames, 
# or is empty, if no files matched.
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"  # print names line by line
```

Note: The `-e` test comes with a tiny caveat: if there are matches and the first match is a *broken symlink*, the test will mistakenly conclude that there are no matches.
A more robust option is to use `shopt -s nullglob` to make the shell expand non-matching globs to the empty string, but note that this is a shell-global option, and it is good practice to return it to its previous value afterward, which makes that approach more cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome answer!

Comment: @ImranAzad: My pleasure; I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put quotes around the whole thing, what you is globbing happening, your command becomes `*` which then is converted to all files in the current directory, this does not happen inside single or double quotes.